# At what points is $f : [0, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous? $f(x) = 11$ if $0 \le x \le 1$, $x$ if $1 < x \le 2$

Tags: real-analysis

I can see that it is continuous on $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$ but I do not know how to prove that it is discontinuous at 1. Also, how would I provide justification that it is indeed continuous on the interval I have stated?

Comment: check $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1- }{ f\left( x \right)  } ,\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1+ }{ f\left( x \right)  } $ at  $1$  point right and left limits will be different

Comment: Just a quick remark : $[0,1] \cup (1,2] = [0,2]$. If you mean that $f$ is not continuous at $\{1\}$, you better tell that it's continuous only on $[0,1) \cup ( 1,2]$ or $[0,2] \backslash \{1\}$

Answer (score 2):

One definition of continuity is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n\to x$, we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Now take $x=1$, $x_n = 1+1/n$. What are $f(x)$ and $f(x_n)$? Does $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that $x\mapsto 11$ and $x\mapsto x$ are continuous for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $x\in (1,2]$ respectively. Note that $f$ is continuous at $a=1$ iff $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)\iff \lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=f(a)\quad \textrm{ and }\quad \lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)=f(a).$$
Can you try to show that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)$?

Comment: So the right sided limit is 1, and the left sided limit is 11, therefore it is not continuous at x=1? How do we justify continuity on the range where we claim it is continuous?

Comment: @user259137 Correct. Since $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)$, the function $f$ is not continuous at $a=1$. The function $f$ is said to be continuous if it is continuous for each $x$ in the domain. Since $1\in [0,2]$ and it's not continuous at the point $1$, then the function $f$ is not continuous (on $[0,2]$).

Comment: I see but how can we prove that it is continuous on the interval [0,1)∪(1,2]

Comment: @user259137 You have to keep it in your mind that the maps $x\mapsto 11$ and $x\mapsto x$ are continuous for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $x\in (1,2]$ respectively (prove it yourself). Combining them, the function $f$ is not continuous at the point $1$, hence it's continuous for all $x\in [0,2]\setminus \{ 1\}$. If you need the proper proof of it using the formal definition of continuity; you'll need the $\epsilon\delta$-techniques. I used the informal definition of continuity in the answer.